# Disable auto-lock in Windows 10 (domain account)

Tags: windows, windows-10, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I have just installed Windows 10 1803 and joined the computer to my domain.
A short while after the display goes into power save mode, the computer also locks so that I have to type the user's password to unlock.

I have already tried editing `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7` and set `Attributes` to `2` to enable "Console lock display off timeout" in the display power options, but increasing that value has no effect. This lead me to believe there is a domain policy somewhere that overrides this setting.

I found something about `Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Interactive Logon: Machine Inactivity Limit`, but this just turns on the screensaver after some time, instead of locking after display has entered power save.

So, is there some other local property I can change, or do I have to modify some domain policy, if so; which?

Comment: `I found something about Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\Interactive Logon: Machine Inactivity Limit, but this just turns on the screensaver after some time, instead of locking`.  That is not accurate. That setting does lock the session, and was created precisely for and only that reason.

Comment: I tried enabling the policy setting I mentioned, but that had no effect. The computer still locks a short while after the display turns off.

Comment: Hi - I'm not disagreeing with you, but there really isn't enough information to assess. For example, you enabled a policy setting. What setting and what is the value? Is it the 'Machine Inactivity Limit'? This seems like it may be the standard Windows Lock Screen Settings > Screen Saver Settings > On resume, display logon screen, but it's hard to know for sure.